# Connecting to external web socket api from Django

Tags: python, django, websocket, slack-api

I am trying to connect to slack RTM (Real Time Messaging) api and update the database with the messages coming from the slack channel. How should I do that.

Should I run a web-socket client in the background? If so, how to integrate the web-socket client with the Django application.

Is Celery something that I should look into? I was looking into this for the past few hours. Went through a lot of questions. I am not able to figure out the right approach to do that.

Comment: I personally find the Events API way easier to use than the RTM API, but it can do the same and works with standard HTTP requests. Check it out

Comment: I have to work with RTM API

Answer (score 0):

You would need a TCP socket.

You will figure out more here: https://realpython.com/python-sockets/

Comment: I want the socket to work along with Django, and thats where I need some light